# Need to do a Report on ALL Campaigns with the Unique ID of Campaign Member status (& filter) in Salesforce CLASSIC

Tags: reporting, campaign, salesforce-classic

Part of the org app has yet to transition to Lightning, so this question relates to Classic and Reports. I need to get a Unique Count of  PICKLIST FIELD linked to a Parent Object 
I can't use UNIQUE COUNT ID as it's CLASSIC. I'm hoping someone can assist, Thanks!

Need to create a report in salesforce on `Campaign Members` (which is a related list to `Contacts` & `Campaigns`) a unique count on
`Campaign Members` with `Contact ID` where the Field `'Status' = 'Volunteers'` - who are both active and inactive 
Per quarter

Currently, the Classic report with a cross filter shows the same volunteers multiple times.

I tried doing creating a Formula Field on Campaign Member `IF(ISPICKVAL(Status, "Volunteer"), 1, 0)` but this did not work. Neither did the Power on One as it has is field value of Object.

What is the best solution here? Would a Joined Report work and what would this look like?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way by switching between Classic and Lightning and then back.

As "Report builder" in Lightning is based on the "Classic Report builder". Reports & Dashboards were never built ground-up for Lightning. 2/ With that understanding, we can follow the rules:
(a). A report created in Lightning could not be accessed in Classic but
(b). A report created in Classic could be accessed AND edited in Lightning.

I created the report in Classic, then switched to Lightning to add the Unique Counter to the Full Name Column.

It is important that when editing the Column you don't put the cursor on the downward cursor on the top right of the column (still shows the Classic options) but instead to go to the EDIT button on the top right of the page and then go back to column to edit where the Unique Values option show up. Equally, if you switch back to Classic the Unique Value is lost. So either export data & save or each time you will have to switch back to Lightning and choose the Unique Values option to view the report.

Alternatively, if you can... just do the the report in Lightning!